# Render_template second time after page is already loaded

Tags: python, ajax, flask, rendering, jinja2

I am trying to query a database through my website and dynamically add columns with the results using Jinja templates. I am using flask and on my views function. I am rendering the values like this

`return render_template('query.html',my_list=my_list )`

The thing is that when I load the page the user hasn't queried the database yet, so my_list is empty. The user queries the database by pressing a button on the html page and making an ajax request through jquery. My question now is if its possible to return my_list using jinja templates even after the page is already loaded, meaning I have to return render_template a second time (after submit button) to get the values for my_list.

p.s. I prefer not to use json parsing.

Here is some sample code. I query the database with the values of intranetID of column SubmitterID and platform of column Platforms to return the whole entry to the database with the values of the rest of the columns as well.

```
@app.route('/querydbvalues',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def querydbvalues():
  if request.method == 'POST' or  request.method == 'GET':
    results = models.mydatabase.query.filter_by(SubmitterID=qIntranetID,Platforms=qPlatform).all()
    my_list = [i.user for i in results]
    return render_template('query.html',my_list=my_list )
```

and on my html page

```
{% for n in my_list %}
<li>{{n}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

on the Javascript file when you press the button i make the ajax request like this

```
$("#SearchDatabase").click(function(){
    var tmp = document.getElementById("qIntranetID").value;
    var tmp2 = document.getElementById("qPlatform").value;
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url:"/querydbvalues", //tell the script where to send requests
        data:{text:tmp,text2:tmp2},
        type:'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(results){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to check the request method. Flask will only route GET and POST requests to that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax call is a completely separate request. You can do what you want in that request, including render templates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. However my problem is that i want to render "my_list" on the same html page without refreshing or changing to another page. And for some reason i cant and thats why i asked for help

Comment: Well that is what Ajax does. You should maybe explain *why* you're having problems rendering the same page, rather than saying "for some reason I can't".

Comment: i dont have problem rendering the same page. I have problem rendering the value on "my_list" (the second argument i render after the html page) and using those values with jinja template on my webpage.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're asking, I'm afraid. You carefully hide your JS success method: it's in there that you need to take the result rendered by Flask and insert it into your existing page.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for baring with me and still trying to help me.
by "return render_template('query.html',my_list=my_list )" i return my results my_list and with jinja templating i can just use the my_list values on my html page like i described on the code above. however when the page is first loaded my_list = [] and only changes values when the user presses submit and the querying to the database happens. Once i get the values i want to my_list i want to return them again to use with jinja templating. This doesn't happen and i cant return the new values of my_list.